# Swift Generate A Random Color On A Colorwheel

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm using the [SwiftHSVColorPicker](https://github.com/johankasperi/SwiftHSVColorPicker) framework and needed to generate a random color on the color wheel.My current way of doing works but something that brightness is off.Here is my code

```
func generateRandomColor() -> UIColor {
    let lowerx : UInt32 = UInt32(0.0)
    let upperx : UInt32 = 707
    let randomNumberx = arc4random_uniform(upperx - lowerx) + lowerx
    let lowery : UInt32 = UInt32(0.0)
    let uppery : UInt32 = 707
    let randomNumbery = arc4random_uniform(upperx - lowerx) + lowerx
    let c = Colorwheel.colorWheel.hueSaturationAtPoint(CGPoint(x: Double(randomNumberx), y: Double(randomNumbery)))
    let brightness = 1.0
    return UIColor(hue: c.hue, saturation: c.saturation, brightness: CGFloat(brightness), alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use something like

```
func getRandomColor() -> UIColor{

    let randomRed:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
    let randomGreen:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
    let randomBlue:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)

    return UIColor(red: randomRed, green: randomGreen, blue: randomBlue, alpha: 1.0)

}
```

**EDIT:**

Try this, In this `hue`,`brightness` is also there

```
func generateRandomColor() -> UIColor {
  let hue : CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 256) / 256 // use 256 to get full range from 0.0 to 1.0
  let saturation : CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 128) / 256 + 0.5 // from 0.5 to 1.0 to stay away from white
  let brightness : CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random() % 128) / 256 + 0.5 // from 0.5 to 1.0 to stay away from black

  return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: 1)
}
```

**SwiftHSVColorPicker** results

[image]

Comment: I couldn't get you, which all colors.

Comment: Unfortunately still didn't work after updated the code.http://oi68.tinypic.com/16ozmo.jpg

Comment: @JamesIkeler Can you explain a bit more what is not working, it is generating some random color codes for me

Comment: I getting a random color for the x & y of the colorwheel and displaying it as a uicolor.

Comment: Yes I checked the edit and it didn't worked for me.I used the same code before.

Comment: you can try different libraries of color picker https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=colorpicker

Comment: I checked the library you are using and it is giving fine results. Check the edit